# Powershell - How to make sure a parameter is of a certain type (ArrayList)?

Tags: powershell, validation, arraylist, parameters

```
function Global:Some-Function {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$InputArrayList
    )

    $debug = $true

    # Empty Validation
    if(($InputArrayList -eq $null) -or ($InputArrayList.Count -le 0)) {
        if($debug) { Write-Host '$InputArrayList is null or count -le 0' }
        return 
    }

    # Verify the Input is an ArrayList
    if($InputArrayList.GetType().Name -ne 'ArrayList')
    {
        if($debug) { Write-Host '$InputArrayList is not of type "ArrayList"' -ForegroundColor Red }
        return
    }
  } # Function
```

While this works, it seems like too much code just to check `$InputArrayList` is  of type `ArrayList` and not `$null`.

How can I specify this in the `param()` section?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler What class is `ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()` from?

Comment: [`ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=validatenotnullorempty) is a PowerShell "parameter decoration"; it is intended to mandate that the passed value is non-null.

Comment: `[System.Collections.ArrayList]$InputArrayList` as param will not work, it will pass even regular array, will not throw error

Comment: @Avshalom I can confirm that.

Comment: @Avshalom it will work depending on what the requirements are - it won't pass a regular array, it will cast it to an ArrayList. That may or may not be desired, but inside the function what you get will be the right type of collection and not anything else.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, It will not for work by validating means, and that what the OP needs, already tested it, define regular array `$arr = @()` and an ArrayList: `$ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList`, you can pass them both and you will not get an error, like passing a `string` to `int` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe Just:

```
function Global:Some-Function {
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $InputArrayList
    )

    return $InputArrayList -is [System.Collections.ArrayList]
  } # Function
```

Comment: Awesome answer! 99.9% sure this is the answer, but I'm going to give it some time to see what else people say

Comment: Here, I will help...It is the answer.

Comment: @EBGreen Honestly, I'm surprised there isn't a built in way to validate type in the `param( )` section. Seems like that is a pretty standard thing to do in a function call

Comment: Why do you need to validate a _specific_ parameter type, when a _compatible_ type will do?

Comment: You can check the type using a ValidateScript block in the param. Then using -is in the block.

Comment: @EBGreen, this will not work as well, because the `$_` will check the content and not the parent type, for example: `[ValidateScript({($_ -is [System.Collections.ArrayList])})]` will not work, but if your ArrayList contain list of PsObjects, this will work: `[ValidateScript({($_ -is [psobject])})]`

Comment: Does it? I was not aware of that. I will have to do some testing.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart What if you try to call `.Add()` on something that isn't an *ArrayList*... or even worse, what if the thing has the `.Add()` method, but it isn't an ArrayList - that would be tough to debug. There's no way to know for sure what is coming in, so it is best to check I feel